# How to add "Play on Phone" button on Facebook Canvas App

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-widgets

I saw the plugin button "Play on Phone" in some games like Candy Crush Saga, Angry Birds Friends that works exactly like "Send to mobile" button in appcenter. I want to add such a button to our game canvas (https://apps.facebook.com/doodle-god/) but I can't find any documentation about this plugin and hardcodding of our AppID in plugin's Iframe code does not helped.

Сan anyone clarify the situation? Thanks.

[image: Candy Crush Saga]
[image: Angry Birds Friends]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work at Facebook, the 'play on phone' button in your screenshot is an experiment we are currently running with a few hand-picked developers. That said, 'send to mobile' functionally is available to you as part of Facebook's App Center and app pages. More details about this option can be found in this blog post: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/05/22/driving-mobile-app-installs-with-the-app-center/

Comment: so this "play on Phone" button is for selected developer's App.its not available for all Canvas Apps right....?